# How do I update a TextView that stores an average of list values

Tags: android, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have an android activity that consists of a List View and a Text View. The Text view displays information about the summed contents of the list view, if the items in the list view are updated then the Text View needs to reflect the change.

Sort of like an observer pattern but with one component reflecting the changes of many rather than the other way round.

The tasks are displayed as items in the list view and the progress can be updated using a seekbar to set the new progress level.

The following method populates the TextView so I need to call this again from inside the SeekBar onStopTrackingProgress Listener.

```
private void populateOverviewText() {
TextView overview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TaskOverview);

if (!taskArrayList.isEmpty()) {

    int completion = 0;
    try {
    completion = taskHandler.getProjectCompletion();
    overview.setText("Project Completion = " + completion);
    } catch (ProjectManagementException e) {
    Log.d("Exception getting Tasks List from project",
        e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

I realise if I want to call the method from the List Adapter then I'll need to make the method accessible but I'm not sure the best approach to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using DataSetObserver

I was looking for a solution that didn't involve altering the adapter code, so the adapter could be reused in other situations.

I acheived this using a DataSetObserver

The code for creating the Observer is incredibly straight forward, I simply add a call to the method which updates the TextView inside the onChanged() method.

### Attaching the Observer (Added to Activity displaying list)

```
    final TaskAdapter taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(this, R.id.list, taskArrayList);

    /* Observer */
    final DataSetObserver observer = new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            populateOverviewText();
        }
    };

    taskAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
```

### Firing the OnChanged Method (Added to the SeekBar Listener inside the adapter)

```
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
    int task_id = (Integer) seekBar.getTag();

    TaskHandler taskHandler = new TaskHandler(DBAdapter
        .getDBAdapterInstance(getContext()));

    taskHandler.updateTaskProgress(task_id, progress);

    mList.get(position).setProgress(progress);


    //need to fire an update to the activity
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either make this method `public`

or you can pass `activity` to adapter through which you can find the button and update text, or can directly pass `Button` to adapter...

Comment: How would I pass the activity to the adapter something like taskListView.setAdapter(new TaskAdapter(this, R.id.list, taskArrayList, getActivity())); Then set the Actvity as a local variable of the adapter ? This seems to couple the task adapter soley to this Activity, I'm using the same task adapter in more than one activity. so That's not a best fit here. The same with the button.

Comment: you said `if I want to call the method from the List Adapter` , if you want to **call** it from list adapter, you can call it/update text view by using the logic i described in answer..(how you have to manage it in diff activities is diff thing,each time you would be passing diff activity context)

Comment: I thought there should be a better fit than simply passing the activity to the adapter, something like a way of registering a listener to see if the items change and if they do change fire the method to update the textview.

Comment: well you can definitely pass a (click/onStopTrackingProgress /etc) listener(from activity) to Adapter and there then bind it to seekbar or anybutton required... This way your logic remains in activity.. the listener is just binded to whatever item required in the listadapter...